# Fastest server for static files serving

Tags: webserver

I was trying to find out what server side technology is best to use for serving static files?

What is used for CDN's serving?

And also I'm interested does it add any performance(for data serving) if you serve static files from different server(hardware) rather than serving from the same server which provides data? Like totally separating Client and Server files.

Comment: This answer may be what you are looking for. https://serverfault.com/a/249524/423055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of technology goes into making a CDN fast;

- Mount your document root as a ramdisk.
- Cache full responses to most common queries rather than rebuilding the http.
- Tweaking swappiness (or having no swap at all)
- Firewall load balancing
- DNS load balancing
- Geolocation load balancing
- Turning off logging/hostname resolution/various lookups.
- Many cores, big pipes.

Comment: This is a great information on related topic, but still what is used as software to server data anyways?